# How to prevent default back behavior in Amazon Fire TV HTML5 web app?

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-fire-tv

I'm trying to override the default back behavior in certain cases, and update my application state rather than fire a history popstate event.

Is there some other event I should hook in to to prevent default behavior? I found the remote back button fires a keydown event with e.keyCode === 27

```js
const FIRE_REMOTE_BACK = 27;
handleBackButton = (e) => {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  // update app state
}
handleKeyDown = (e) => {
  const {keyCode} = e;
  
  if (keyCode === FIRE_REMOTE_BACK) {
    return handleBackButton(e);
  }
}
```

I see my application state updated briefly, but then back event completes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered my own question. Listen for the 'keyup' (not keydown) event and preventDefault()

Answer (score 1):

In my case (FireOS 7 WebView Chrome 88) I also had to add the following:

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Otherwise I would get the remote key interaction to double fire.